# Cardinal of a set of functions between two finite sets of integers

Tags: combinatorics, functions

> Let $ A= \{a_1, a_2, a_3,\cdots, a_{10}\}$, $B=\{ 1,2 \}$. Find the number of functions $ f: A \to B $ such that $ f(a_1) +f(a_2)+\cdots+f(a_{10})$ is an even number.

I have tried to find the number of functions $ 2^{10} $ But not getting any clue to find the functions under such conditions.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Intuitively, the number of such maps is $2^{10}/2$: there is the same number of maps such that the sum is even, vs. the maps for which the sum is odd.

To prove it, prove that there is a one to one correspondence between the maps such that $f(a_1)=1$, vs the ones for which $f(a_1)=2$.

Answer (score 0):

To see it as an arrangement problem. Let our mapping be permutations of $\{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\}, \{2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\}, \{2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\}$ and so on...

To get an even number as the output you need to select permutations of sets that have even number of one's. Let $P_{10}$ be permutations of $\{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\}$, $P_{9}$ be permutations of $\{2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1\}$ and so on..
$$\
\text{Required Permutations}=P_0+P_2+P_4+P_6+P_8+P_{10}
$$
You can compute each term and find the answer or you can use symmetry and argue that this will be equal to $\frac{2^{10}}{2}$ as pointed out by mathcounterexamples.net

Answer (score 0):

So you have to take even members from $A$ which are maped to $1$.

So you need to find out the number of subsets of $A$ with even cardinality, and that is: $${10\choose 0}+{10\choose 2}+...+{10\choose 10} = {2^{10}\over 2} $$

---

More interesting question would be if we take $B=\{1,2,3\}$